# How to programmatically select LI from UL using java script in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to programmatically select an option (LI) from UL from a web site, using a Chrome Extension. The HTML code from the website is as follows;

```
<ul class="select-options">
<li data-value="0" class="select-items selected">0</li>
<li data-value="1" class="select-items">1</li>
<li data-value="2" class="select-items">2</li>
<li data-value="3" class="select-items">3</li>
<li data-value="4" class="select-items">4</li>
<li data-value="5" class="select-items">5</li>
<li data-value="6" class="select-items">6</li>
<li data-value="7" class="select-items">7</li>
<li data-value="8" class="select-items">8</li>
<li data-value="9" class="select-items">9</li>
</ul>
```

This is my javascript code in content script;

```
var xPath = "//ul[( contains(@class,'select-options') )]";
let lst = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
if (lst != null)
{
    //For example, How to programmatically set the second LI (The item with data-value="1") selected here?
}
```

Can anyone please point me in right direction to set an specific item selected programmatically, similar to user manually selecting an item from the drop down list?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? (ex: hide item or change styling)....you can select them usign css pseudo class. See more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: @VitorMartins I'm trying to automate the manual user action of selected item changing from current value to another value.from the dropdown

Comment: If that UI control is a script generated `<select>` replacement it probably won't be as simple as changing the classes. Will probably need to trigger click event or if there is a hidden `<select>` it is bound to , change the value of it. Not really enough known about what it does when selected by normal user interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks got too complex which can be achieved simply. I assume the website does not belongs to you, and just need to automate an user action on the list. If so, try it in the following way.

```
function setItem(digit)
{
    var xPath = "//li[( (@data-value='"+digit+"') )]";
    let lst = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (lst != null)
    {
        lst.click();
    }    
}
```

I used the same XPath way since your sample code uses that way.

Comment: it worked perfectly in this way. Everything updated on the website as expected and just what exactly I looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

While XPath is certainly *an* option, it's not the most common (by far).

Use a combination of [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with the appropriate [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and modify the element's [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

The purpose of `ul.select-options` is to narrow down your selection on the page to avoid side-effects.

```js
function select(item) {
  // Clear the previously-selected item
  document.querySelector('ul.select-options li.selected').classList.remove('selected');
  
  // "Select" the new item.
  document.querySelector('ul.select-options li[data-value="2"]').classList.add('selected');
}

select(2);
```

```css
li.selected {
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="select-options">
  <li data-value="0" class="select-items selected">0</li>
  <li data-value="1" class="select-items">1</li>
  <li data-value="2" class="select-items">2</li>
  <li data-value="3" class="select-items">3</li>
  <li data-value="4" class="select-items">4</li>
  <li data-value="5" class="select-items">5</li>
  <li data-value="6" class="select-items">6</li>
  <li data-value="7" class="select-items">7</li>
  <li data-value="8" class="select-items">8</li>
  <li data-value="9" class="select-items">9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with:  function setDigit(digit)
{
    // Clear the previously-selected item
    document.querySelector('ul.select-options li.selected').classList.remove('selected');
    
    // "Select" the new item.
    document.querySelector('ul.select-options li[data-value="'+digit+'"]').classList.add('selected');
}    It sets the desired item selected when checked in code. but however previously selected item still selected and showing as selected. Also it seems other stuff on page does not affect similar to manual selecting. What should I do further to correct it? Thanks.

Comment: @nawala Instead of modifying class use `.click()` on the one you want. High probability there are event listeners involved that do other things when user triggers a click

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. Yes that way everything worked as normal similar to user click. Thanks again.